# Not in document field array mongodb with $expr

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to get all documents that don't have an `_id` in the array `excluded`.

```
db.sites.find({ "$expr": { '_id': { "$not": { "$in": "$excluded"} } } });
```

I'm not using `$nin` because it's not allowed under `$expr`.

I'm getting the following error message:

```
Error: error: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Expression $in takes exactly 2 arguments. 1 were passed in.",
    "code" : 16020,
    "codeName" : "Location16020"
}
```

Can I use `$where` for this instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) operator requires two arguments:

```
db.sites.find({ $expr: { $not: { $in: [ "$_id", "$excluded" ] } } })
```

Working example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ce7yf4eb-n-)

Comment: @psykx please don't, there are just two `$in` operators in MongoDB and you tried to use the one for queries but you needed the one for aggregations

Comment: Aaahhhh. Ok. That makes sense.